# Bloquear campos dependiendo de valor en dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, html5

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño formulario en **C#** y **.NET** y requiero hacer algo así como una validación, estoy intentando que cuando tenga el valor *CERRADO*  en el dropdownlist de *Estatus* automáticamente se bloqueen los demás campos, quiere decir, que queden en modo de solo lectura algo así como `readOnly`, incluyendo su boton de *Enviar*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto a continuación el código de mi formulario en `html` y la función **Javascript** para cargar los datos

```js
function loadTicketDetails() {
    $(".fixed-action-btn").floatingActionButton();
    $(".fixed-action-btn").show("slow");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    document.getElementById("modalAceptNew").style.display = "none";
    const url = document.getElementById("allTicketData").value;

    window.hasRun = true;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").setAttribute("value", data.CustomerEmail);                       
            document.getElementById("ticketAreaAppliInput").setAttribute("value", data.CustomerArea);
            document.getElementById("ticketLocationAppliInput").setAttribute("value", data.CustomerLocation);                   
            $("#CategoryDiv select").val(data.CategoryId);
            $("#StatusDiv select").val(data.Status);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Ocurrió un error al cargar los datos, porfavor inténtalo de nuevo.");
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
                               
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="email" for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    
                                </div><div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="area" for="ticketAreaAppliInput">Área:</label>
                                        <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketAreaAppliInput" type="text" name="area" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="ubicacion" for="ticketLocationAppliInput">Ubicación:</label>
                                        <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketLocationAppliInput" type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="CategoryDiv">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="category" for="ticketCategoryInput">Categoría:</label>
                                        <select onchange="validate(this)" id="ticketCategoryInput" name="category" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option><option>Categoria 1</option>
                                        <option>Categoria 2</option>
                                        </select>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="StatusDiv">
                                    <label for="ticketStatusInput">Estatus:</label>
                                    <select id="ticketStatusInput" name="status" class="form-control form-control-user" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option><option>Abierto</option>
                                        <option>Cerrado</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                
                                <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

**Actualización:**

El valor *CERRADO* viene desde otra vista quiero decir, cuando ingreso a los detalles para ver la información de ese formulario (que ya debería estar cargada) si en el campo Estatus se encuentra el valor *CERRADO* que se me muestre todos los campos en solo lectura y así permitir que no se pueda modificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes deshabilitar los campos con jQuery asi:

```js
function loadTicketDetails() {
    $(".fixed-action-btn").floatingActionButton();
    $(".fixed-action-btn").show("slow");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    document.getElementById("modalAceptNew").style.display = "none";
    const url = document.getElementById("allTicketData").value;

    window.hasRun = true;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").setAttribute("value", data.CustomerEmail);                       
            document.getElementById("ticketAreaAppliInput").setAttribute("value", data.CustomerArea);
            document.getElementById("ticketLocationAppliInput").setAttribute("value", data.CustomerLocation);                   
            $("#CategoryDiv select").val(data.CategoryId);
            $("#StatusDiv select").val(data.Status);
            if (data.Status == 'Cerrado') {
              $(":input").attr('disabled', true);               
            } else {
              $(":input").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Ocurrió un error al cargar los datos, porfavor inténtalo de nuevo.");
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
                               
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="email" for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    
                                </div><div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="area" for="ticketAreaAppliInput">Área:</label>
                                        <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketAreaAppliInput" type="text" name="area" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="ubicacion" for="ticketLocationAppliInput">Ubicación:</label>
                                        <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketLocationAppliInput" type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="CategoryDiv">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="category" for="ticketCategoryInput">Categoría:</label>
                                        <select onchange="validate(this)" id="ticketCategoryInput" name="category" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option><option>Categoria 1</option>
                                        <option>Categoria 2</option>
                                        </select>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="StatusDiv">
                                    <label for="ticketStatusInput">Estatus:</label>
                                    <select id="ticketStatusInput" name="status" class="form-control form-control-user" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option><option>Abierto</option>
                                        <option>Cerrado</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                
                                <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Creo que no fui muy claro explicando, el valor CERRADO viene desde otra vista quiero decir, cuando ingreso a los detalles para ver la información de ese formulario (que ya debería estar cargada) si en el campo Estatus se encuentra el valor CERRADO que se me muestre todos los campos en solo lectura, espero que me puedas entender.

Comment: La logica seria igual, solo tienes que remover el handler `change()` y mover el codigo dentro de la llamada Ajax

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Simplemente remueve la linea.  Ya edite.

Comment: Tienes idea de como hacerlo en el controlador, o sea en el backend ?